# Connect to Tor Network using 'eduroam' authenticated internet

Tags: configuration, network-configuration, proxy, blocked-services, mac

I am struggling to connect to the Tor network. I am using a university internet connect which itself requires authentication to connect to. When first connecting to the eduroam network, a user provides there login details, which triggers the download of the authentication certificate that my computer then automatically uses to connect to the network at any later date.

I believe that when connecting to Tor, I must follow all manual config (bridge and local proxy settings), however I do not know how to find the 'Proxy Type', 'Address' or 'Type'.

I am using the latest Mac OS X. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

The following screenshots show the windows I am presented with during the connection process:

[image]

The final window is where I am struggling to find the correct settings for.

Selecting no proxy, give me the following error message, after an attempted connection:

[image]

Comment: How did you install Tor? Via homebrew? or downloading the browser from the website?

Comment: I installed Tor by downloading the browser from the website

Comment: ok, my answer below should work then. let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to find the bridges info at [bridges.torproject.org](https://bridges.torproject.org).

Download the Tor browser if you haven't already and change the settings in the browser to connect using bridges.

Follow the steps from the link I provided and paste the bridge information it provides you into your Tor Browser. Then you should be GTG.

Note, on that same linked page the Tor staff states another method to get bridge information:

> Another way to get bridges is to send an email to bridges@torproject.org. Please note that you must send the email using an address from one of the following email providers: Riseup, Gmail or Yahoo.

So even if you can get a bridge from the website you can email them directly.

Here is what your network settings should look like in the Tor Browser (not the local proxy, I am using privoxy for mine):

*redacted to hide bridge info*

Tor settings location, click on Onion then Tor Network Settings:

[image: onion screenshot]

Solution using meek bridge:

*image redacted to hide meek connection info*

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried using the bridges as you have advised, however I don't think that's where the problem is. The problem is with configuring the 'Local Proxy Configuration'. I assume that I will need to provide my login detains as the 'Username' and 'Password' fields, however I don't know how to find the correct IP address and Port. Any idea how I could overcome this?

Comment: in your 'Tor Network Settings' enter your custom bridges. Then check the box that says "this computer goes through a firewall that only allows connections to certain ports". That should get you through and mask your traffic through 443 / 80.

Comment: In response to your edit; I am not able to open the settings dialog that you have shown above. The only settings I can access are the initial connect dialog which appears at Tor's first open.

Comment: @Harvs It is in the Onion icon to the left next to the url bar. Click it, and then click "Tor Network Settings". I added screenshot of onion icon to answer.

Comment: What I'm saying is that because I've reinstalled Tor, the browser window never opens, the first (and only) window to appear is the connection window.

Comment: @Harvs that is actually the first time you said that the browser window never opens. When the connection window opens, there is a settings option right there. click it and edit your bridge settings. There is also the option that says "my ISP blocks TOR connections" click that, depending on what you are seeing. If you would describe in detail the actual issue you are having in the first place, you would avoid unnecessary troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear, I am having trouble explaining whats happening. What would be the easiest way for me to post screenshots to you; so that you can see exactly whats happening?

Comment: @Harvs imgur.com links once you upload them there is easiest probably. On OSX use CMD + Shift + 4 and drag to do a screenshot of exact area of screen where issues occurring.

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the configuration window that I have. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: ah, makes more sense now. just check no. your logged in system on your computer should already be connected already

Comment: try going to google.com once browser loads, if doesn't work then follow my steps to click on onion and edit settings to go through firewall 80,443

Comment: I have added an additional screenshot to show that result.

Comment: @Harvs that IP address is in your custom bridge setting, remove that line and try again (save settings and restart browser).

Comment: Well spotted! I have tried removing it, but the same happened will all 3 of the IPs in the bridge settings

Comment: did you turn on the firewall setting or off?

Comment: try this: turn off the firewall setting and add this in for the only bridge line (a meek that I am using): `bridge meek 0.0.2.0:1 url=https://scfith-bridge.appspot.com/ front=www.google.com` that way it looks like you are routing all traffic through google.com, which your university is not blocking.

Comment: @Harvs I updated my answer with screenshot of meek solution. Don't use the local proxy setting that I have checked. That is the only thing different.

Comment: @Harvs no problem. Enjoy

Comment: shouldn't we sanitize bridge IP addresses, lest they are publicly disclosed?

Comment: @blau yes Harvs needs to remove screenshots of their bridge info and I will remove mine. Mine is less problematic because according to tor-devs on irc the meek-google bridges are completely different than the bridges provided from bridges.torproject.org. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just start the eduroam VPN normally. Then start Tor like on a normal connection, without configuring any proxies in the launcher (the options you are listing are not for VPNs). And you don't need bridges either, eduroam doesn't censor.

Comment: Thank you, think is correct; I didn't need any proxies. eduroam doesn't censor but unfortunately my provider does. Heavily! However the above solution using a meek bridge worked for me.

Comment: By definition and rules the brand EDUROAM only applies to cable or wireless networks authenticated by University credentials using 802.1X. There are no EDUROAM VPNs.